# Limit points of a subset of a topological space.

Tags: general-topology

Determine the set of limit points of $A=\{1/n+1/m : n,m \in \mathbb Z^+\}$ in the standard topology on $\mathbb R$.

I think that the limit points of $A$ is $A'=\{0\}$. Am I correct? How would I prove this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you gonna get more than $0$. For instance, the  numbers $1/n$ will all be limit points...

Comment: Check [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/143061/191019). This proves a generalized version.